# Is there any way to focus the mechanical vibration or stress of an object?

Tags: applied-physics

I am looking for a way to focus the vibration of a metal sheet at a specific point on that sheet so that other points vibrate less. Just like light and lens. Is there any way to focus the mechanical vibration or stress of an object?

Comment: Perhaps engineering.stackexchange would be more suitable for your question.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will post it in engineering forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is. I furnish two cases here.

First we take the case where the vibration wavelength is of order ~the physical dimensions of the part. For small parts, this implies ultrasonic waves. These can be focused and concentrated by artfully tapering the part towards the zone where you want the vibrations concentrated and by adding chunks of mass upstream of the tapered zone to  place a displacement maximum at the end of the tapered zone. This principle is used in the design of what are called *ultrasonic welders* that are used to friction-weld plastic parts together. The piece of metal used to carry the ultrasonic waves from the generator to the part to be welded is called the *horn* and adjusting its mass distribution is called *tuning the horn*.

The second case is where the vibrating part is flexible enough that its resonances come about through macroscopic flexure, as in the case of a thin vibrating membrane like for example a drum head. In the acoustics field this sort of vibration is called *oil-canning* and if you are designing a noise-blocking enclosure for a loud piece of machinery, you must avoid this because the enclosure becomes acoustically transparent if the enclosure walls are resonant like this at the noise frequency.

Oil-canning can be reduced by "clamping" the enclosure walls either with internal struts that prohibit movement of the wall or by adding mass to the center of the wall panels to move their resonances away from the noise spectrum of the source. The opposite can be done by deliberately tuning the acoustic compliance of the air inside the enclosure coupled to the mass of the vibrating wall so the fundamental excitation frequency of the system (air + wall) is a close match to one of the dominant frequencies in the noise spectrum of the source. In this case, the noise control enclosure makes the noise source a more efficient noise radiator and the noise problem becomes *worse*.

This effect is used in musical instruments like a marimba, in which the wooden bars are backed up with tuned lengths of tube which are resonant at the bar frequencies.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detail information. 
I appreciate such valuable comment.

Comment: @zeynab, to officially "accept" my answer, click on the checkmark icon to turn it green.